# Use default `ubuntu` user to deploy an app or make separate users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, user-management, user-permissions, best-practices

I have a Ruby on Rails app and use Capistrano to deploy it to the server.

The deploy user and the user running the app is the same - the default `ubuntu` user. (this has sudo access: `ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`)

Maybe this setup is a bit insecure, in case there is a flaw in my Rails app that allows access to the system via the `ubuntu` user?

I was thinking of making these two users:

1. `deploy` user: only has sudo access to start/restart `nginx` on the server. Has SSH access to the server.
2. `railsrunner`: no sudo access, and has no SSH access (`railsrunner:x:12345:12345::/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin`)

Is that a good approach? Is there any advantage to having a `deploy` user or the `railsrunner` user or should I just use the `ubuntu` user? (or something else?)

Comment: You should make the users you need to accomplish the objectives you want to achieve. As for the default user, you probably should just ignore its existence entirely except when configuring a new instance.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: *Is there any advantage to having a deploy user or the railsrunner user or should I just use the ubuntu user? (or something else?)*